# Reorder Methods and Parameters in Laravel Routes

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-3

I'm building a REST API using controllers in Laravel 3, and I'd like to achieve the following structure:

```
/api/controller/{param}/method/{optional param}
```

Currently, I have individual routes set up for each method, which seems like a tedious solution:

```
Route::any('api/ControllerA/(:any)/MethodA/(:any?)','api.ControllerA@MethodA');
Route::any('api/ControllerA/(:any)/MethodB/(:any?)','api.ControllerA@MethodB');
// etc.
Route::any('api/ControllerB/(:any)/MethodA/(:any?)','api.ControllerB@MethodA');
// etc.
```

and at the end, a catch-all to handle invalid calls:

```
Route::any('api/(:all)',function(){
    // return invalid call 404 response
});
```

This works just fine, but I can't imagine this being the optimal solution. I might consider doing something like [this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378799/dynamic-routing), but I feel like that would lead to some bulky API controllers. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Laravel 3 doesn't support urls like `controller/{param}/method/{param}` without defining them manually. Laravel 4 supports that but only for default resourceful routes (index, show, update, delete, etc). You cannot define custom actions tho.

I would suggest you to stick with your approach for now. It's what we've being doing on Laravel 3. If you really dislike that, you could extend `\Laravel\Routing\Router` with your own implementation.

Comment: Alright, I'll stick with it. It gets a bit cumbersome, but at least I get to see all my possible calls explicitly outlined in one place.

Comment: Btw, you could create a base `API_Controller` and extend it. On that controller you could handle api specific logic like returning that 404 json. Take a look on `Base_Controller::__call` as an inspiration.